# Block windows key wxPython

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I am creating an application with wxpython for writing tests in schools, and it needs to be able to block the windows key, alt-tab and so on to prevent cheating. Is this possible and if it is, how do you do it?

I know that you can't block ctrl + alt + del, but is it possible to detect when it is pressed?

Comment: As a general rule, you probably won't get this to work to your satisfaction.  I plug in a USB drive - this causes a popup and the windows start menu to appear, and I have now left the application without hitting any keys.  Press the power button once - that shifts focus back to the OS.  Insert headphones, that sometimes causes an audio driver popup.  Unplug network cable for a few seconds, that causes a popup-balloon from the task bar that I can click on to change focus. Hit shift-shift-shift-shift-shift for the stickykeys dialog... The ways to get around this are endless.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in a similar discussion, http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/track-session-events.html

Which provides an outline of tracking user events such as those triggered by a ctrl + alt + del press.

It may provide a workaround to having to block the keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is No, unless this is a touchscreen application with no access to the computer hardware. That would probably work. Otherwise you'll have to look into how to lockdown your PC with Microsoft Policies etc. Or you might be able to do it with a locked down Linux install. Regardless, it's not really something you can manage with wxPython. It's something you have to manage at the OS level.